# My Win 7 "default" spell checker has bad word "added" can not find it, even searching disk for that word

Tags: windows-7, spell-check, dictionary

My most misspelled word `teh` got added to my spellchecker's dictionary somehow.  It has been about 3 months and is a serious productivity issue.  When writing this question, spellchecker works but did not catch the `teh` above. I am such a bad typist / speller that it has caught 3 other errors so far.

I run Windows 7 on an ASUS PC with an i7 chip.  I have found a spellchecker file it does not have `teh`.  My Libre Office does work riight; it must use its own exception file.

I just added `youresdelf` to the spellchecker and again Search cannot find it.

My default spellchecker seems to be Goggle as when I clicked on `riight` above, the box with option to add it to dictionary mentions Google; I will attach a screen shot of that.  I have found "dictionary.txt" but `teh` is not in that file. The "custom dictionary.txt" file is in the Chrome folder does have added words in them but no `teh` or `youresdelf`.

Note I added `youresdelf` in the same box as image below and it appears to work because it took off the red underline but I cannot find `youresdelf` on the disk even with searching inside files.

[image: SpellCheck add box image]

Note: I use Chrome and search with Google but the "Default speller"  seems to work just about everywhere except in LibreOffice

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: There is no "default" Windows 7 spell checker - each application will generally use its own, with its own custom dictionary. If you are using Chrome, follow Coles answer.

Comment: Hi David, Actually missed your question yesterday.  I have no recall of setting any speller but here on superuser, thru Chrome, Cole's solution worked and still is working on "teh" which did just highlight.  However in Windows Live/Hotmail/Outlook, "teh" does not highlight even though other words do?? Hmm.  The same Spell menu that mentions Google I attached Friday comes up, so now am confused.  Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, try this:

Click the three bars on the upper right of the browser to open the menu
click Settings.
Click Advanced Settings at the bottom of the page
Click the Language and input settings... button under the category "Languages" Then click "Custom spelling dictionary" at the bottom.

See if it's in there.

Comment: Yee Haw!!   Yes, just as you said.  Had to scroll a lot as list not alphabetic,  but was there.  And teh now is redlined!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Cole, that solution is still working here on Superuser, but just noticed in Hotmail/Outlook it is not?  Will copy in what just replied to David with:            David: Actually missed your question yesterday. I have no recall of setting any speller but here on superuser, thru Chrome, Cole's solution worked and still is working on "teh" which did just highlight. However in Windows Live/Hotmail/Outlook, "teh" does not highlight even though other words do?? Hmm. The same Spell menu that mentions Google I attached Friday comes up in Hotmail, so now am confused. Any ideas anyone? –

Comment: Found This  http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/How_to_Use_the_Windows_Live_Hotmail_Spell_Checker.htm   To correct a misspelled word (marked with a red underline), click it and select the desired alternate spelling.
Note that Windows Live Hotmail's built-in spell checker does not work in Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome and possibly other browsers that do themselves check the spelling of text you type.              So that indicates Hotmail uses the Chrome speller, so mystery it works here on Superuser, but not in Hotmail?